# Как вырезать все вхождения в массив?

Tags: javascript

Допустим есть строка:

`Текст $var{m1}, еще текст + $var{m2}, еще текст $var{m3}`

**Цель:** на выходе получить такой массив `['m1','m2','m2']`

Я пробовал сделать так:

```
str.replace(/\$var\{.{0,}\}/g,()=>{
        console.log(arguments);
});
```

Но в `arguments` попадает не то что нужно.

Как правильно вырезать все вхождения в массив?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```
let getVars = (re,s) =>{
    let r = [], m;
    while(m = re.exec(s)) {r.push(m[1]);}
    return r;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const re = /\$var\{\w*\}/g;
const re2 = /\w\d/g;

let str = 'Текст $var{m1}, еще текст + $var{m2}, еще текст $var{m3}';
let arr = str.match(re);

let res = arr.map(item => {
  return item.match(re2)[0];
});

console.log(res);
```